# How to resize rotation radius using css

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

How to resize balls rotation radius so that they should touch the orange contaner border

```css
.bg {
    background-color: blue;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.ball-container {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.ball {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;

    top: 125px - 12px;
    left: 125px - 12px;

    animation-name: ball_moves;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: initial;
}

.ball:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.ball:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: top right;
}
.ball:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.ball:nth-child(4) {
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

@keyframes ball_moves {
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

    <div class="ball-container">
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Adjust transform origin values.

Comment: I tried this but couldn't move all four balls in different directions as they are moving now in all four directions. Can you help me a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS variables to define a unique offset that can control all your circles using transform-origin:

```css
.bg {
    background-color: blue;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:10px;
}

.ball-container {
    --d:35px; /* adjust this like you want (you can even use % value)*/
    /* 
      1) we first find the middle of each small square
        the size is 250/2=125 so we translate by (125-24)/2 = 50.5px
        this will put the origin in the middle and give us a rotation 
        following the "circumscribe" circle so we the circle will go outside
      2) we need to decrease it to keep the rotation inside
         the calculate is a bit complex but we decrease by around 15px to have 35px
    */
    
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px,
      linear-gradient(red,red) center/1px 100%,
      orange;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.ball {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;

    animation-name: ball_moves;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: initial;
}

.ball:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: calc(-1*var(--d)) calc(-1*var(--d));
}
.ball:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: calc(-1*var(--d)) calc(100% + var(--d));
}
.ball:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: calc(100% + var(--d)) calc(-1*var(--d));
}
.ball:nth-child(4) {
    transform-origin: calc(100% + var(--d)) calc(100% + var(--d));
}

@keyframes ball_moves {
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

    <div class="ball-container">
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="bg">

    <div class="ball-container" style="--d:100%;"> <!-- 100% = 24px (size of circle) -->
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Using another syntax:

```css
.bg {
    background-color: blue;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:10px;
}

.ball-container {
    --d:47px; /* adjust this like you want (you can even use % value)*/
    /* 
      1) we first find the middle of each small square
        the size is 250/2=125 so we translate by (125)/2 = 66.5px
        this will put the origin in the middle and give us a rotation 
        following the "circumscribe" circle so we the circle will go outside
      2) we need to decrease it to keep the rotation inside
         the calculate is a bit complex but we decrease by around 15px to have 47px
    */
    
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px,
      linear-gradient(red,red) center/1px 100%,
      orange;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.ball {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;

    animation-name: ball_moves;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: initial;
}

.ball:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: calc(50% - var(--d)) calc(50% - var(--d));
}
.ball:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: calc(50% - var(--d)) calc(50% + var(--d));
}
.ball:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: calc(50% + var(--d)) calc(50% - var(--d));
}
.ball:nth-child(4) {
    transform-origin: calc(50% + var(--d)) calc(50% + var(--d));
}

@keyframes ball_moves {
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

    <div class="ball-container">
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="bg">

    <div class="ball-container" style="--d:200%;"> <!-- 100% = 48px (size of circle) -->
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You put the right calculations but how did you do that? Can you help me for understanding this so that I can guess right values for future animations.

Comment: @WasiF The calculation is simple, You have 4 balls and they all going to go in opposite sides from each other, so we can assume that one will have two positive edges, another two negative edges and the last two will alternate. you can do this blindly if you don't care about order.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I calculated the values from Temani given calculations: they, I think, cannot calculated blindly, atleast for me because they are not one of `220%` or `120%` but a mixture of `220%` and `120%`, here are these: `.ball:nth-child(1) {
    transform-origin: -120% -120%;
}
.ball:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: -120% 220%;
}
.ball:nth-child(3) {
    transform-origin: 220% -120%;
}
.ball:nth-child(4) {
    transform-origin: 220% 220%;
}`

Comment: The values set in the `--d` are arbitrary it's meant to show you how you can solve the problem easily and it's for you to adjust. You can see the comment he put next to it in the css code. If you go through those calculations you can see that it's just multiplying by negative value to go backward or adding to the maximum height/width to go forward

Comment: @WasiF the transform consider the coordinate 0,0 so to go in the negative step I simply do (0 - offset) and to go to positive step I do (100% + offset) because I need to consider the other corner to have a symetric rotation for all. Now for the offset imagine your orange square divided into 4 small square and I need to put the origin of each circle in the middle of the square so I need to perform a translation. the width of circle is 24px and each small squre 125px so the offset need to be (125px - 24px)/2 = 50px but this will give a rotation around the corners so I decrease it.

Comment: @WasiF I decrease it to have an inside rotation and when I use 120% it mean 120% of the width/height of the circle which is simply equal to 28.8px. I used both % and px to show that both works the same but the calculation need to consider both your square and circles dimension

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you for detailed explanation. I cannot absorb it all. I have a bit confusion that when you put negative value, you set i.e. `-120%` but when put positive value, you  set i.e. `220%`, almost double of the negative value by assuming the `--d: 120%`. Why not set `-220%` and `220%` for all either they are going in any direction by giving +ve or -ve value. Can you please refer me such article that explains these things in detail.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why you are adding `100%` with +ve values but not with -ve values?

Comment: @WasiF it's not the double it's 100% + offset ... it's because the reference of each element is its top/left not its center. So if I do -d I need to do 100% + d becasue 100% will move us to the opposite corner then we add an offset

Comment: @WasiF here is another syntax where I guess it would be easier to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/pke2wL3f/ .. I consider 50% in all the cases then either + or -

Comment: Thank for your precious time and effort. You made things easy for me.